# Reclaim disk space after drop table from database in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have this version of MySQL server:

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.15 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

I use a some large tables. When I truncate database with `truncate database <name>`, I check the hard disk space and I've noticed my disk space is not reclaimed.

This is more information on my server:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table';
'innodb_file_per_table', 'ON'`
```

Any idea to resolve this ?

Comment: How large was this table?  Was file_per_table set to `ON` _when the table was created_?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to "reorganize/rebuild" the table truncated  which can be achieved by below.

   mysql> OPTIMIZE table table_name;

for InnoDB tables, it run under ALTER operation.

reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html